# GAS won't run GmailApp.getUserLabelByName onEdit

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google Apps Script (GAS) to create an email draft when a record is added to my spreadsheet.

I use `onEdit` to call my method (greatly simplified) like this:

```
function onEdit(e){
   populateCache("test");
}
function populateCache(label){
   Logger.log("before");
   var thisLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label);
   Logger.log("after");
}
```

This logs "before", but never reaches "after", and I don't get any errors. If I call the method manually via debug, it works as expected.

Why would this line fail via `onEdit`?

```
var thisLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label);
```

How do I get it to work?

Comment: Did you set a trigger of "onEdit()"? When there is no trigger of it, a permission error occurs.

Comment: That worked! If you mark it as an answer, I will accept it. I wonder why the code executed until that part without an issue.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I summarized it as an answer. Please confirm it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the situation by following script. When "onEdit()" isn't registered as a trigger, a permission error displayed to "Logger.log(e)". The error disappears by registering the trigger. And 'Logger.log("after")' was executed.

```
function onEdit(e){
   populateCache("test");
}
function populateCache(label){
  Logger.log("before");
  try{
    var thisLabel = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(label);
  }
  catch(e){
    Logger.log(e)
  }
  Logger.log("after")
}
```